# How do I compare text files with a text dictionary and give a specific color to the matched text?

Tags: python

I have a `keyword_file` and a `log_file` and I want to compare these two files and highlight the whole line of matched text.

```
keywords_file = open('keyword_file')
keywords_dict = {word: 0 for word in keywords_file.readlines().strip().split(' ')} # Iterate through all the words removing '\characters and generate a dict

# Then read the chat log
chat_log_file = open('log_file')
chat_log_words_generator = (word for word in chat_log_file.readlines().strip().split(' ')) # Create a generator with the words from the chat log


for word in chat_log_words_generator:
    try:
        word_count = keywords_dict[word]
    except Key-error:
        continue # The word is not a keyword
    word_count += 1 # increment the total
    keywords_dict[word] = word_count
```

I got the above code from internet but it failed. The error message I got was this:

```
is...
Trace back (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    keywords_file = open('keyword_file')
FileNotFoundError: [Err-no 2] No such file or directory: 'keyword_file
```

Comment: what's your file extension? and does the file `keyword_file` exist in the root of your python script?

Comment: the extension is .txt

Comment: try  `open('keyword_file.txt')`

Comment: still not working...

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    keywords_dict = {word: 0 for word in keywords_file.readlines().strip().split(' ')} # Iterate through all the words removing '\characters and generate a dict
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: Please could you show us where you got the code that failed?

Comment: ***"AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'"***: Thats correct, you have to `strip()` every `line`.

Answer (score 1):

## Compare log file with keyword file and highlight matched text on console

Code:

```
import os

dir_path = 'M:/Desktop/Python-Test/'
keyword_file = os.path.join(dir_path, 'keyword_file.txt')
log_file = os.path.join(dir_path, 'log_file.txt')

with open(keyword_file, 'r') as file1:
    with open(log_file, 'r') as file2:
        file1_txt = file1.read().strip().split()
        file2_txt = file2.read().strip().split()
        gen_list = ['\033[1;37;40m{}'.format(word) if word in file1_txt else '\033[0;0m{}'.format(word) for word in file2_txt]

gen_str = '\033[0;0m '.join(gen_list)  
print(gen_str)
```